# Finding $ \oint\limits_C \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,\mathrm ds$ where $C$ is the circumference $x^2 + y^2 = ax$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to evaluate this line integral $\oint\limits_C \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\,\mathrm ds$
where $C$ is the circle curve $x^2 + y^2 = ax$. I did use parametrization by this equation:
$$
x = x(t) = \frac{a}{2} \cos(t) + \frac{a}{2}; y = y(t) = \frac{a}{2} \sin(t)
$$
but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I see where you coming from with that since it centers the integral at the center of the circle. But perhaps it would be easier to use "normal" polar coordinates even though that would make $r = r(t)$ instead of a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use the usual polar coordinates inspired parametrization we get that

$$r^2 = ra\cos t \implies r(t) = a\cos(t)$$

which gives us

$$\vec{r}(t) = (x(t),y(t)) = (a\cos^2(t),a\sin(t)\cos(t))$$

$$\vec{r}'(t) = (-a\sin 2t, a\cos2t) \implies ds = |\vec{r}'(t)|dt = a\:dt$$

Then the integral becomes

$$\oint_C \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\:ds = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}a^2\cos t \:dt = 2a$$